# How to return empty result for columns in a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a stored procedure which returns results with some values, but I need to return empty values for all columns if the given input date is a weekend.

I used an `IF` clause with checking dataname and return empty result set, but I have to type every column in that stored procedure to return empty value if that `IF` clause is true.

My code:

```
declare @RunDate date = '20190504'

IF DATENAME(WEEKDAY, @RunDate) NOT IN ('Saturday','Sunday')
BEGIN
    Do the actual Logic
END
ELSE
    ' ' as field1, ' ' as field2,..........' ' as fieldN
```

This returns the correct result as I expect, but there are more stored procedures and each stored procedure may have multiple columns, so typing

```
' ' as field1, ' ' as field2,.........., ' ' as fieldN
```

is tedious.

Is there any way to return the columns with empty string if the given date is on weekend? Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: hi i think select ' ' as field1, ' ' as field2,..........' ' as fieldN
 do what your're you whant

Comment: Return nothing and have your app check for no rows returned.

Comment: You can use suitable `union all select '', '', ....` to avoid typing field aliases. Of course Dale's approach is much better, unless some part of your code expects recordset structure being constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply a trick like below-

```
DECLARE @RunDate date = '20190504'

IF DATENAME(WEEKDAY, @RunDate) NOT IN ('Saturday','Sunday')
BEGIN
    --Do the actual Logic
    --For Example
    SELECT * FROM your_table
END

ELSE
BEGIN
    --Do the tricks
    SELECT * FROM your_table
    WHERE 1= 2 -- This will never return a row!! But the column names :)
END
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not a fan of returning values from stored procedures.  I much prefer user defined functions, if that is appropriate.

In any case, store your results in a temporary table:

```
select . ..
into #resultset 
. . .;
```

Then add conditional logic as the last step:

```
select rs.*
from #resultset rs
where DATENAME(WEEKDAY, @RunDate) NOT IN ('Saturday', 'Sunday')
```